# Running Swagger Editor on Windows 10

Tags: npm-install, swagger-editor

I am trying to run a swagger editor locally on windows 10. I am getting the following error with npm i swagger-editor.
Trying to spin up a static server.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-editor

Error:
[image]

Here are the node & npm versions:
E:\VS\LocalDev\swaggereditor>npm -v
5.6.0

E:\VS\LocalDev\swaggereditor>node -v
v10.1.0

Comment: looks like you need to create a package.json. So write `npm init -y`

Comment: Thanks i did that but after that too npm start gives error.

Comment: Yes, you probably need to add the script `npm start` to the package.json. Have you created any `index.js` file, or have you only installed swagger-editor?

Comment: only installed swagger-editor where it got above issue.

Comment: Alright. The issue from start is that you didn't have the `package.json`-file. Now, you have issues that `npm start` isn't available. You have only installed a package, now you need to create a javascript file that handles the package and sets it up. Try to see if you can find a guide on how to install swagger-editor